# wordpress upload image http error multiple times

Tags: wordpress

i go to Wordpress 3.5 after we moved it to production server, and uploading an image first caused it to uplad 2 times, next time 4 times, last time tried the once uploaded image to uploaded 64 times... dont know where to check and what to look for, any ideas?

if trying to upload from article - insert image, then it even shows me an red http error but still image uploads multiple times

Comment: Any messages in Javascript console? Do you see anything unordinary when debugging the media-views.js? Are you sure it's not a problem with incompatible plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the issue, our webhosting provider is very flexible in range of possible options and for some reason I found our testing server had preset a 5.3 php, while the new production website had as default the 5.2, after changing it to 5.3 in the adminpanel of webhosting, magically all thing began to work ok.

Sooo **issue solved**, while still funny for me that pure **changing of php between 5.2 - 5.3** may change such major issues in usability of wordpress